# Couchbase RX Client - Merging multiple observables vs flatmap

Tags: java, performance, rx-java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

What is the performance difference between the following code snippets?

Use case: retrieve multiple keys from Couchbase using the Couchbase reactive SDK.

Snippet #1

```
 return Observable
            .from(keys)
            .flatMap(id ->
                    bucket.get(id, RawJsonDocument.class)
            )
            .toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .single();
```

Snippet #2

```
     List<Observable<RawJsonDocument>> list = new ArrayList<>();
     keys.forEach(key -> list.add(bucket.get(key, RawJsonDocument.class)));
     return Observable.merge(list)
            .toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .single();
```

The first snippet is the recommended way according to CB's [documentation.](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/java-2.2/documents-bulk.html)

> Also, at the very end the observable is converted into a blocking one,
>   but everything before that, including the network calls and the
>   aggregation, is happening completely asynchronously.
>
> Inside the SDK, this provides much more efficient resource utilization
>   because the requests are very quickly stored in the internal Request
>   RingBuffer and the I/O threads are able to pick batches as large as
>   they can. Afterward, whatever server returns a result first it is
>   stored in the list, so there is no serialization of responses going
>   on.

The second snippet is a case we found in our codebase today, where there's a list of Observables, where each observable triggers a get method of Bucket one by one and then merges them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no performance difference between the two snippets, from the perspective both of the Couchbase SDK and RxJava, they are very similar (as `flatMap` basically do a `map` to `Observables` like your keys.forEach, then `merge` the observables in a loop).

edit: from a personal perspective I still prefer the first style though ;)

Answer (score 1):

What `flatMap` does it invokes mapper function for each key, then merges results of these invocations. I don't expect this merging algorithm to be any different from the one used in `merge`. So in case `bucket.get()` is non-blocking, there should be no performance difference between the two.

Snippet #1 looks more readable to me.

Comment: Agree, editing the second snippet just to make the question clearer. RX-wise, I understand the performance should be identical. I wonder if there's a difference on how the SDK manages its inner buffer and resources when invoking those 2 examples.

Comment: @shays10 By same algorithm I mean same or very similar internal implementation. Therefore there should be no differences in any aspect.